# ¿como hacer un patron de solo conteo de caracteres en Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

quiero hacer una validación de solo conteo de caracteres, pero me sale error. Creo que el passwordPattern lo estoy haciendo mal...

```
fun  Activity.isValidatePassword(password: String): Boolean{
    val passowrdPattern = "^(?=\\S+\$).{8,}"
    val pattern = Pattern.compile(passowrdPattern)
    return pattern.matcher(password).matches()
}
```

si me pueden ayudar, estaré altamente agradecido

Comment: Recuerda agregar siempre información acerca del problema, en este caso que error obtienes?, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: se que el problema el el patron ya que antes estaba usando este  val passowrdPattern =  ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%!\-_?&])(?=\S+$).{8,} osea (1 number   / 1 ltr lowercase / 1 capital ltr  / 1 special character  / 8 min character), pero ahora solo quiero que el patron sea de contar solo un minimo de x caracteres , pero me sale error y no me deja hacer en este caso el registro del usuario.